# is it safe/good practice to "reuse" CompletableFuture

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

When experimenting with `CompletableFuture`, I was wondering if the given code is safe.

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> foo = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 42);

foo.thenApply((bar) -> {
    System.out.println("bar " + bar);
    return bar;
})
.acceptEither(foo.thenApply((baz) -> {
    System.out.println("baz " + baz);
    return baz;
}),
(z) -> System.out.println("finished processing of " + z));
```

It works, printing

```
bar 42
baz 42
finished processing of 42
```

Is it safe/a good idea to call `thenApply` or other methods more than once on a given instance of `CompletableFuture`?

Comment: Just for reference, this question has been discussed on concurrency-interest last month. See [this](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2016-July/015299.html) thread. I wouldn't reuse CompletableFutures in general (mostly because they're mutable).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you describe is not a “reuse” of a `CompleteableFuture`, as it still performs only one action and completes at most once.

You are just registering multiple dependent stages, which is completely within the foreseen usage. At no point, the documentation suggested that dependent stages had to form a single linear chain. The use case is already described by the [interface `CompletionStage<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html):

> A stage of a possibly asynchronous computation, that performs an action or computes a value when another CompletionStage completes. A stage completes upon termination of its computation, but this may in turn trigger other dependent stages.

Note the use of “*other dependent stages*” rather then “*another dependent stage*”. The entire documentation consistently uses plural when it comes to dependent stages. This also applies to the documentation of the `CompletableFuture<T>` implementation class.

After all, when you have two actions *a* and *b* which have no dependency to each other but a dependency to *c*, the only thing that makes sense, is to chain both to *c* rather than create a chain like *c* → *a* → *b* or *c* → *b* → *a* as the latter would inhibit the concurrent execution of the independent actions *a* and *b*, which is the entire point of the concurrency API.

Note that when modelling the dependency this way, there is no guaranty of the outcome you have shown. The two printing actions “bar” and “baz” have no dependency on each other, but only on the supplier of the `42` value, and the action which prints “*finished processing*” is scheduled for the completion of *either* of them, *not both*. So besides the indeterminate order of the “bar” and “baz” output, you could also see a log like “bar, finished processing, baz” or “baz, finished processing, bar”.

Comment: I guess in the examples I have encountered, there was only one dependent action. But obviously it would be a quite severe limitation if only one action was allowed. But then the question remains: What is real reuse which was discussed in concurrency-interest? Using methods like obtrude?

Comment: It was about a scenario where a method returns a `CompletableFuture` and it may return the same already completed future on each invocation, if that matches its semantic. That method would break, if someone uses one of the `obtrude…` methods on the returned future, but I wouldn’t call that a real problem. If a developer involved in your project wants to break the application, there will always be a way (say hello to Reflection with access override…). The `obtrude…` methods are clearly outside normal use cases. The other issue mentioned there only applies to futures which never complete.